# Is there any way to use NAudio.Lame with Xamarin (Android/iOS) applications?

Tags: c#, xamarin, naudio, lame

I'm trying to use NAudio.Lame to convert recorded audio from wav to mp3. I have installed the nugget package(v 1.1.1) with NAudio(1.1.0) but when I try to compile the application it shows this message:

`` /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `LameDLLWrap`, referenced by `NAudio.Lame`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `LameDLLWrap`, or remove the reference to `NAudio.Lame`. (XA2002) (MyApp.Droid) ``

The [official page](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/blob/240bd28c7c4a33a2b7dbc267c4401c64cd9316be/README.md) at GitHub says:

> IMPORTANT: Because this wraps Windows native DLLs it will not work on
>   any operating system. It may function with Windows emulation layers
>   but I have never tested this.

Any chances of using it in a Xamarin Android/iOS project?

Comment: No, it depends on Windows DLLs that do not exist on iOS/Android.

Comment: @Jason answer the question and I will accept it as correct one.

Comment: Can you please write the answer and accept if Jason don't. It will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Jason comments and NAudio.Lame official page, the answer is NO, because it depends on Windows DLLs that do not exist on iOS/Android.